# Where is the most recommended place to store files / pictures with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing a website with Node.js. The general data is stored in PostgreSQL.
As far as I understand, it is not recommended to store files / pictures in a database.
I'll say I'm using a photo gallery so I'll have to pull out many pictures.

**Where should I store my pictures, and how?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can store your images on any cloud storage as there will be lots of image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store images in db other than storing them as base64 or buffer data which is very arguably efficient. Store them either on your SDD or use CDN or any other cloud service and store links in your db, let the client's browser do the downloading job. If you choose to store them on your ssd raise separate NGINX (if you prefer this service) instance (in sites_available) with folder index option, do not choose NODEJS image serve for the sake of speed (nginx is much faster in static serve).

Use converter to webp format since it is the most progressive web image compression yet, demands the most less storage space and is fastest for your clients. If your clients are scattered across the globe use CDN, so that they receive cached images from the closest to them cdn cache server.